# Stuck in definite integration

Tags: integration

[image]

In this I tried to substitute x by $\pi /2 - x $  , but after that  got stuck

Comment: In an irrelevant note, it's quite beautiful that the graph of $f(x) = \cos^{10}x \cdot \sin 12x$ looks like a heartbeat diagram.

Comment: $sin12x=sin(11x+x)=sin11xcosx+cos11xsinx$

Comment: @imranfat I don't think it is of great use .

Comment: integration by parts on $cos^{10}xsin11xcosx$ as well as $cos^{10}xcos11xsinx$. Now behind both integral signs you get trig terms you can combine since integrals are based on same interval. When you do that and think again of sum formula for sine, thinks look better

Comment: @Koolman Instead of dismissing someone's hint after only thinking about it for less than two minutes, maybe you should try harder.

Comment: Koolman: If you judge suggestions irrelevant, without having checked out the suggested path, and you've done virtually nothing prior to your post, and expect someone to do all the work for you, and spit back to you "A,B,C,$ or "D", then you're not at the correct website.

Comment: @imranfat sorry ,but Still I could not understand how to use integration by parts .

Comment: $\frac{1}{11}$ is the right answer

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner but how ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using indicated sum formula for ${\sin12x}$ on the integral we get

$$I=\int({\cos^{10}x}{sinx}{\cos11x}+{\cos^{11}x}{\sin11x})dx$$.

Now break up the integral in two.

First we have $$\int({\cos^{10}x}{sinx}{\cos11x})dx$$.

Choosing $f'=cos11x$ and doing integration by parts we get $$\frac{cos{11}xcos^{11}x}{-11}-\int{sin11xcos^{11}x}dx$$.

For the second part we get $$\frac{-cos^{11}xcos11x}{11}-\int{cos^{10}xsinxcos11x}dx$$.

Pease note that their first parts are equal, let's call that $A(x)$. When we add the integrals, we arrive at $$2I=2A(x)-\int{sinxcos^{10}xcosx+cos^{10}xsinxcos11x}dx$$.

Factoring out $cos^{10}x$ and apply the sum formula for sine, you obtain the original function behind the integral sign, so $I=2A(x)-I$ from which $I=A(x)$ follows.

The $\pi/2$ does not contribute and the answer follows from plugging in $x=0$. This is the method in short, it is up to you to work out the rudiments. My class is coming up, forgive my formatting (Amwhy)